# TaxJar returns 0 for all states except Nexus address state

Tags: magento2, tax, sales-tax

For my magento2 store, taxJar Api is returning 0 tax value for all states except the address of my Nexus. I add Texas address as nexus and it is working fine for it. Should I need to add all states as nexus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to collect sales tax in US states where you have [nexus](https://blog.taxjar.com/sales-tax-nexus-definition/). So if you only have nexus in Texas, you would only collect sales tax in Texas and not elsewhere. TaxJar will not return sales tax for states where you don't have a nexus address set up.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is the behavior or the way Tax works in USA. You only collect tax from the states where you have nexus.

Comment: For anyone interested in better understanding what this "tax nexus" stuff means, I recommend this video: https://youtube.com/watch?v=ETJB643qHU4&t=2m51s TL;DR: you need to pay a % of tax in states you sell more than $100k/year or 200 transactions/year there